# Присоединительное тире

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

По-русски ли будет таким образом соединить предложения? Или лучше поставить точку?

Конструкция задвижки ZTS была оптимизирована под конкретные условия эксплуатации на электростанции в Мангейме — это, например, сферический корпус, который позволяет снизить термическое напряжение.

или:

Конструкция задвижки ZTS была оптимизирована под конкретные условия эксплуатации на электростанции в Мангейме. Это, например, сферический корпус, который позволяет снизить термическое напряжение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше поставить присоединительное тире, в этом случае вторая часть БСП  раскрывает тему, являясь пояснением с дополнительным присоединительным значением.